# How To count specific Word in a loop In php

Tags: php, count

I want to use break in php on a specific word I have an example for it

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    // break on specific word
}
```

my curl code here

```
echo $output;
if(stristr($output,"remainExpireTimeSec") {
    $tott=count(remainExpireTimeSec)-1; //remainExpireTimeSec word count
    if ($tott == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

if "remainExpireTimeSec" word comes 5 time in loop then break

but it didnt work any help please

Comment: Do you want it to break if the word occurs more than 5 times? Or should it break if the word occurs at least 1 time?

Comment: word should come 5 times in loop

Answer (score 0):

Following code will return the number of "remainExpireTimeSec"s in the $output string.

```
substr_count($output,"remainExpireTimeSec")
```

and if it's equal to 5 you can break

```
if(substr_count($output,"remainExpireTimeSec") == 5){
    break;
}
```

or you can use it on your for loop initialization

```
for($i = 0; $i < substr_count($output,"remainExpireTimeSec"); $i++){
    //your code
}
```